# Emacs 28.1: Bash Shell Script Indenting does not recognize if [....];then

Tags: indentation, script

Since upgrade to Emacs 28.1, I have noted an annoy change in shell-script mode auto-formatting.

I would like to recover the old behavior

Before, if I entered

```
if [ "$x" = "" ];then
    export x=$y
fi
```

and then enter new line, the new line would align with the fi

```
if [ "$x" = "" ];then
    export x=$y
fi
cp fred ethel
```

Now it I do the same thing I get the new line indented

```
if [ "$x" = "" ];then
    export x=$y
fi
    cp fred ethel
```

The matching code also does not recognize that the fi is connected to the then statement.

This is not the case if I break the if into two lines:

```
if [ "$x" = "" ]
then
    export x=$y
fi
cp fred ethel
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you see the change when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. It might represent an intentional change, but it might not. A bug report will be responded to with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this and it seems like a bug (please do report it), but you can work around it by putting a space after the semicolon (which I think almost everyone does, which would explain why this wasn't spotted by anyone).

Comment: Yes, that will fix the issue.  I will report a bug, as this is a change in behavior.